# Angular validators and ng-maxlength use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

I've got the following div, which I want to add the bootstrap's class "has-error" if the input length is over 50 characters. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{has-error:[formData.titulo.$error]}">

    <label for="inputTitulo">Título</label>
    <input type="titulo" class="form-control" id="inputTitulo" 
           maxlength="50" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="formData.titulo">

</div>
```

How can I make this work? I guess when you reach 50 characters, ng-maxlength throws a error, like the $error object, but I have no clue on what object is, how to access it, and if I have to do some more work in the controller or directive.

Any help here? I can't find any "easy" info regarding this issue and Angular validators.

edit 1:

I've seen all your responses, learned something new thanks to you, but this is still somehow not working. It currently is this way:

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': formData.titulo.$error.maxlength}">
    <label for="inputTitulo">Título</label>
    <input type="titulo" class="form-control"  id="inputTitulo" maxlength="50" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="formData.titulo">
  </div>
```

Also tested checking the length directly, as one of you suggested. But none of these solutions seem to work: it never adds the has-error class. Why?

Comment: IF you want only validate with maxlength then you could use `ng-class="{has-error: formData.titulo.$error.maxlength}"`

Comment: As I explained below, the input's `ngModelController` is published under the `name` of the directive. You need to add `name="titulo"` to your input for your attempt to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the errors published on the scope, a `form` directive is required.

```
<div ng-form="form1" ng-class="{'has-error': form1.text1.$error.maxlength}">
  <input name="text1" ng-model="formData.foo" ng-maxlength="50">
</div>
```

(Notice that the above uses the `name` attribute of the input to publish the form data - really, the `ngModelController` - on the scope)

So, the above works, and it's preferable if you do form validation. But, if you just need to check the length of some input, you don't have to use form validation - you could just check the model directly:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': formData.foo.length > 50}>
  <input ng-model="formData.foo">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be more explicit, thanks... (I didn't use it since `ng-maxlength` was the only validation directive applied)

Comment: Thats looks perfect now.. +1

Answer (score 0):

as you are using ng-model to make validations ,, this class *ng-invalid* will be added to your input 
docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

to use $error you need to access it using forms and names not ng-model ,, and the ng-class should be bound to the $error.maxlength not $error only

tutorial : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

If you use the maxlength, a user will never be able to enter more characters than that, so you will never get the ng-maxlength error. It doesn't make sense to use maxlength and ngMaxlength together IMHO.

See the example on [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength) (open the example in plunker and add maxlength attribute)